# XQL select following element

Tags: xml, xpath, element

Is there a way to select element which stands just after an element, that satisfies some condition with XQL?
I have the below structure:

```
<parent>
<child>
    <a>AA</a>
</child>
<child>
    <a>BB</a>
</child>
<child>
    <a>CC</a>
</child>
<child>
    <a>DD</a>
</child>
<child>
    <a>EE</a>
</child>
```

I want the value of /child/a which stands just after /child/a = 'DD'
With xPath i am using

```
/parent/child[./a = 'DD']/following::child/a
```

but there is no `following` or `following-sibling` function in XQL.

Comment: So the expected result is `<a>EE</a>`?

Comment: Expected result is EE

Answer (score 0):

With the sequence operators ';;' (precedes) and ';' (immediately precedes.).
Although these operators are not included in the XQL spec.

Example:
With the following input:

```
<TABLE>
  <ROWS>
   <TR>
    <TD>Shady Grove</TD>
    <TD>Aeolian</TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
    <TD>Over the River, Charlie</TD>
    <TD>Dorian</TD>
   </TR>
  </ROWS>
 </TABLE>
```

Find the TD node that contains "Shady Grove" and the TD node that immediately follows it:

```
//(TD="Shady Grove" ; TD)
```

Example:
With the following input (from Hamlet):

```
<SPEECH>
  <SPEAKER>MARCELLUS</SPEAKER>
  <LINE>Tis gone!</LINE>
  <STAGEDIR>Exit Ghost</STAGEDIR>
  <LINE>We do it wrong, being so majestical,</LINE>
  <LINE>To offer it the show of violence;</LINE>
  <LINE>For it is, as the air, invulnerable,</LINE>
  <LINE>And our vain blows malicious mockery.</LINE>
 </SPEECH>
```

Return the STAGEDIR and all the LINEs that follow it:

```
SPEECH//( STAGEDIR ;; LINE )
```

For reference [link](http://search.cpan.org/~enno/libxml-enno-1.02/lib/XML/XQL/Tutorial.pod#Precedes_-_';;')